# Can u please tell me what this piece of code means

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can u please tell me what this piece of code means:

```
- (id) initWithNumber: (int) n {
    self = [super init]; 
    if (self) {
        self->_number = n;    
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: That's basic Objective-C. It seems you need to learn the language, for example from a book, or take a course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
- (id) initWithNumber: (int) n {
```

This is an initializer that takes an `int` named `n` as it's only parameter.

```
    self = [super init];
```

As in many OO languages, `self` is the name that represents the "current" object. You don't usually assign a new value to `self`, but you do it in an initializer because it's actually legal in Objective-C for an initializer to return a different object than the one that was allocated. It's very rare that that actually happens, but it *could* happen, so the convention is to assign the result of the superclass initializer to `self`. Speaking of that, `super` is a keyword that actually means the same object as `self`, but tells the compiler to start the search for matching methods in the superclass. `super` is how you call inherited methods. So, this line calls the inherited method `init`, which initializes the object as far as the superclass is concerned, and assigns the result to `self`.

```
    if (self) {
```

It's possible that the `[super init]` failed for some reason, and if so it will have returned `nil`. It's important to check that the object is not nil before doing any further initialization.

```
        self->_number = n;
```

This is a silly line. Since `self` is a pointer to an object, it's legal to dereference that pointer and access the fields of the underlying structure, which is what the `->` operator does. But the current object is already in scope, so you could just say `_number = n;` instead keep things simple. Instance variables are always in scope in your instance methods, so you never need `self->...`.

```
    }
    return self;
```

As described above, initializers need to return a pointer to the object, so here you return `self`.

```
}
```

Comment: `self->_number = n;` is exactly equivalent to `_number = n;` and does not save any operations. Both statements dereference `self` when accessing the ivar. In both cases the address from self might already be in a register and is not loaded again from somewhere. Both probably do not result in a single store but have to query the runtime for the ivar's offset. You're right that the explicit `self->` is redundant, though.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe You're quite right -- I was thinking more of brain operations than CPU cycles, but given how I wrote it I'm sure most people would interpret it the other way.

Comment: After re-reading I think my comment sounded disregarding and a bit wisenheimerish. That was not my intend. I appreciate when someone takes the time to answer beginner's questions in such breath, so I already upvoted your answer. And I did not think you're not aware of my addition, I just wanted to point it out more.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe On the contrary -- I definitely appreciate that you clarified the point. I was too casual in writing *save a few operations* -- any programmer would take that as "it's more efficient to use `_number` compared to `self->_number`, but as you say they're exactly the same. I really just meant that `_number` is conceptually simpler for the programmer. I've seen code where every ivar access is prefixed with `self->`, and it just adds complexity. But I should've said that more explicitly. So thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 0):

What do you really want to know?
It is a initial code of a class, and in this method, the instance property `number` is set with the value `n`.